# Bashrc, shell script and crontab

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, bashrc

I'm trying to use the functions defined in `/home/my_username/.bashrc` in a shell script that gets executed by crontab.

```
#crontab -l

# m h  dom mon dow   command
  * *  * * * /bin/sh /home/my_username/CronTab_shell_script.sh >> /home/my_username/Desktop/file.log
```

Let's say I have the mounted() function saved in

```
/home/my_username/.bashrc 

function mounted(){

    if mount|grep $1; then
    echo "mounted"
    else
    echo "not mounted"
    fi

 }
```

How can I call and use the mounted() function from the

```
/home/my_username/CronTab_shell_script.sh
```

Comment: The easiest way is to put this function into the body of `CronTab_shell_script.sh` :)

Answer (score 7):

### 1. Run the correct shell

```
* *  * * * /bin/sh .....
```

You are not running `bash`, you are running `sh`, so you should not expect `.bashrc` to be loaded!

Try this instead:

```
* *  * * * /bin/bash .....
```

### 2. Work around Ubuntu's default .bashrc

Another problem might be that Ubuntu's default `.bashrc` script starts with this guard:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Any lines you add below this will not be loaded by your cron script because cronjobs do not run in an interactive environment.

The solution: Put functions for scripts ***above*** this guard.  Keep setup for the user ***below*** this guard.

## 3. Load the complete user login environment

On some systems I find its easiest to use `--login` to ensure the shell has the same things loaded that I have at the command line.

```
* *  * * * bash --login /path/to/script.sh

* *  * * * bash --login -c "your command here"
```

Answer (score 2):

Cron runs with a limited shell and won't have access to your regular environment.

You could put `source /home/my_username/.bashrc` at the beginning of `/home/my_username/CronTab_shell_script.sh` to make the function available.

You could also source your .bashrc in your crontab:

```
#crontab -l

# m h  dom mon dow   command
  * *  * * * . /home/my_username/.bashrc; /bin/sh /home/my_username/CronTab_shell_script.sh >> home/my_username/Desktop/file.log
```

Comment: +1, but I think the Shell must be `bash`, it should be declared into the beginning of the script as `#!/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` should be removed from the cron job. Also, maybe, the function should be exported after its definition in `.bashrc` : `export -f mounted`.